# center element before applying animate.css

Tags: html, css, center

I have a div that is of a known width but an unknown height (height:auto).

It needs to animate into view and then be centered both vertically and horizontally in the browser.  It's parent is the body.

I am using the animate.css CSS library to perform the animation.

If I use translate to center the div then the animation offsets the div down and to the right and then,  when the animation is finished, it "snaps" back to the center of the screen.

I am guessing it is some conflict with the translate ?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Include a working example

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you set the layer with position absolute and plays with translate something like this

HTML

```
<div class="container-layer">
  <div class="layer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-layer {
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    display:block;
    }
.layer{
  -webkit-animation: animation 2s linear;
    margin: 0;
    max-width:90px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }

@keyframes animation {
   0% {
    transform: translate(200%, 200%)
   }

   100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
   }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/rjmfbyg9/2/

You are using animate library but I think it works the same